# Apache Commons FileUtils check if file exists in ftpurl

Tags: java, url, io, apache-commons

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(ftpUrl, destFile);
```

Is there any way I can check if a filename exists in the FileURL on the ftp location?

ftpURL: ftp://username:pwd@ftp.abcd.com/filename

**Version used:** commons-io-2.1.jar. I looked at commons-io.2.4.jar directoryContains() looks right but its only to check for a file in directory and not for FTP URL.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe commons-net is more appropriate for your needs.  It provides an API for FTP clients.

Comment: wont you get an IOException if the url doesn't exist?

Comment: @BrentWorden: Checking that.. sounds good..

Comment: @user2242863 I do get the exceptions.. Thats why i was looking to avoid exceptions.

Comment: you can just catch that exception and handle accordingly, look at example below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

When you can instance of FTPClient in youe class you can use following method

```
boolean checkFileExists(String filePath) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filePath);
        int returnCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if (inputStream == null || returnCode == 550) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: minus 1 since the code doesn't work reliably. I queried 2 different files that both existed and it returned true then false

Answer (score 0):

just catch the exception and handle accordingly

```
boolean fileCopyWorked =false;
try{

  FileUtils.copyURLToFile(ftpUrl, destFile);
  fileCopyWorked=true;
}
catch(IOException e){
  // indicates there was an error; handle accordingly 
}
```